# WPGlobus Multilingual - REST API

Tags: plugins, multi-language

I'm using WPGlobus plugin with REST API, For fetching data from posts now if I fetching content of pages it shows me like,

```
"content": "{:nl}De korting wordt automatisch berekend aan de hand van o.a. aantallen stuks, order grootte en aantal adressen.\r\n{:}{:en}The discount is automatically calculated on the basis of, among other things, the number of pieces, order size and number of addresses.\r\n{:}"
```

Instead of this I need,

NL = De korting wordt automatisch berekend aan de hand van o.a. aantallen stuks, order grootte en aantal adressen.

EN = The discount is automatically calculated on the basis of, among other things, the number of pieces, order size and number of addresses.

So question is how can I differentiate content by language.

Comment: For your output, do you mean you want the output to vary depending on a language request parameter, or you mean change it from the `{:nl}` format to your equals format but as a single string, or something else?

Comment: And at first glance from the [WP Globus FAQ](https://wpglobus.com/faq/wpglobus-json-api-support/) this should just work. So possibly worth raising a support request with them?

Comment: @Rup - You are right I need output to vary depending on a language request parameter. Unfortunately https://wpglobus.com/faq/wpglobus-json-api-support/ doesn't work for me